# Issue with Magento 301 redirect on Nginx

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, nginx, 301-redirect

As the subject states, I have some issues with my redirects. 
I have setup 301 to redirect non-www to www and changed it from the Magento EE admin panel too. For the root domain non-www works absolutely fine so for example, if I typed mywebsite.com, it'd redirect me to www.mywebsite.com which is fantastic but if I type mywebsite.com/mycategory, it redirects me to the home page instead of www.mywebsite.com/mycategory. It'd want it to redirect to www.mywebsite.com/mycategory/

I am on Nginx server and 301 redirects are enabled on the server too. I am using Cloudflare as well but no redirect blocking rules are setup there.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: what is your nginx redirect rule?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. Try this...

Under System => Configuration, go under General, and select the Web tab.

Change "Auto-redirect to Base URL" to *No*

Comment: I agree with @SamC this is how you can prevent that auto redirect to the home page if the user just puts in whatever.com/mycategory instead of www.whatever.com/mycategory.